# Qt MousePress/Release filter for Dial

Tags: qt

While implementing a custom dial, I looked at QDial, and noticed two conditions in the [mousePress](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qdial.cpp.html#277)/[mouseRelease](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qdial.cpp.html#300) handlers I do not understand namely:

```
e->buttons() ^ e->button()   //mousePress

e->buttons() & (~e->button()) //mouseRelease
```

It looks to me that the buttons field is xor'ed with the button (masked out in the second condition, but same effect), which should be true if another button is involved in the event. I do not see why a release of the button should be ignored, if two buttons are released at the same time. What are these conditions guarding against?